# Looking to integrate button with block in Json [slack]

Tags: json, json.net, markdown, slack, slack-block-kit

I'm looking to integrate the button with block id using modal in slack, not able to successfully integrate so far now, not sure what I'm missing here also I'm a newbie in JSON so definitely might be missing something minor here. So basically when someone clicks the review button it should pop up with another form. I would really appreciate it if someone can provide some inputs here. Thanks in advance

Testing can be pretty much done here - https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder

```
"blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager Dwight! *Michael Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\n\n *Please select a restaurant:*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*Farmhouse Thai Cuisine*\n:star::star::star::star: 1528 reviews\n They do have some vegan options, like the roti and curry, plus they have a ton of salad stuff and noodles can be ordered without meat!! They have something for everyone here"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "image",
                "image_url": "https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/c7ed05m9lC2EmA3Aruue7A/o.jpg",
                "alt_text": "alt text for image"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Review",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "click_me_123",
                    "title": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "hello world"
                    },
                    "submit": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Submit"
                    },
                    "blocks": [
                        {
                            "type": "input",
                            "element": {
                                "type": "plain_text_input",
                                "action_id": "ml_input",
                                "multiline": true,
                                "placeholder": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                    "text": "If you need help, please review it here detail"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    "type": "modal"
}
```

Comment: not familiar with slack, but I think this is not a json format: you need a "`{`" at the very beginning and "`,`" before `"type": "modal"` right after the `]`

Comment: Tried that still not working, not sure what I'm missing here

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Could you please take a look, if you got a sec.